# understanding method use inside a class

Tags: python

I'm new to classes, this is a small piece of code I've written, but I'm still really shaky on this concept, and am wondering exactly how the method `node_name` comes into play here and if it's even needed?

```
from rdflib import BNode

class HigherNode(object):
    def node_name(name):
        return name

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.node_type = kwargs.get('node_type', 'cog_con')
        self.position = kwargs.get('position', 0)
        self.node_id = self.node_name
        self.node = kwargs.get(self.node_name(), BNode())

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'This is the node of {} in the graph'.format(self.node_id)
```

I behavior that I'm seeking is something equivalent to this:

```
elephant = BNode()
```

when used as:

```
some_node = HigherNode(node_id = 'elephant')
```

Comment: I don't understand the section where you say "I'm seeking something equivalent to this" at all. You assign a string to `node_name` and then immediately replace it with a class instance. What behavior do you think is happening there?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist err..sorry what I mean is for whatever variable name I can come up with, for example `elephant`, so `elephant = BNode()` should be equivalent to, `some_node = HigherNode(node_id = 'elephant')`

Comment: So assigning a class instance of one class to a variable will cause a completely different class to be instantiated with that variable's name as a string argument? That... doesn't make a whole lot of sense. There's almost certainly a better way to do whatever you're hoping to do.

Comment: `self.node_name` is a function reference. For `self.node_name()`, I think that is going to return `self` (which you've given the name of `name` for it) unless you do `def node_name(self, name):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first off, methods have to be called by an instance of the class. So, your behavior would look something like this:

```
# create an instance
node = HigherNode()

# get the name
print node.node_name()
```

However, you never declared name inside the class. So, you'll have to do something like this:

```
def node_name(self):
    return self.name
```

(All instances pass a reference to themselves to thier functions when called, so you'll always have to have at least one variable in the function call. You don't have to call it self.)

Really, it looks like what you want is actually a name setter/getter.

### Try this:

1. Declare/set the variable in **__init__**.

   ```
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.node_name= kwargs.get('node_name', None)
   ```

   Then you can use the variable like this:

   ```
   # create an instance
   node = HigherNode()

   # get the name
   print node.node_name

   # set the name
   node.node_name = "bluh"
   ```
2. Since your class extends object, use getter/setter properties.

   ```
   @property
   def node_name(self):
       return self.node_name
   @node_name.setter
   def node_name(self, x):
       self.node_name = str(x)
   ```

   These are called exactly the same as above in option 1:

   ```
   # create an instance
   node = HigherNode()

   # get the name
   print node.node_name

   # set the name
   node.node_name = "bluh"
   ```

   I prefer this method, since it allows you much more control over how things are set, or even whether or not you *can* set or get them! (Just make a getter property without a corresponding setter property, for instance.)

   However, this second method is more work to set up and may not be suitable for simple variables.